# How do I convert a varchar containing a number in scientific notation to a numeric in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, type-conversion, numeric, varchar

I made some calculations using function and get the following value. I want to divide this value with 1000.

```
1.83673e+006
```

I want to convert the value into numeric.

When I try to convert it to numeric it throws

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Is it possible to convert this value to numeric? Please help me to get this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST(1.83673e+006 AS FLOAT))
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, scientific notation (`...+e...`) is only used for floating-point data types, not for decimal/numeric data types.

Thus, SQL Server recognizes this format only when converting to a floating-point data type (such as `float` or `real`), not when converting directly to `numeric`.

Obviously, nothing prevents you from converting the value to `float` first and then to `numeric`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(19,4), CONVERT(float, '1.83673e+006'))
```

yields `1836730.0000`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
Declare @data varchar(100)='1.83673e+006'
SELECT @data=CAST(CAST( @data AS float) AS NUMERIC)/1000
SELECT @data Result


Result
1836.730000
```